# Find sequence of complex numbers $\{z_k\}$ such that $z_k \to 0$ and $ e^{1/z_k} \to 2+i$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a sequence of complex numbers $\{z_k\}$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} z_k = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} e^{1/z} =2+i$.

Text book doesnot really explain this assignment based question.
$$
e^{1/z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} z^{-k}$$

Comment: The exponential function is continuous, analytic, sugar spice and everything nice. The limit of $exp(x_k)$ should go to $exp(k)$ with $k$ the limit of the $x_k$ sequence. So the limit should be indeterminate. Something might be off in the question? Perhaps there should be a summation in the exponential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is to find 'a' logarithm of $2+i$. Verify, using basic trigonometry, that $$e^{\ln \sqrt 3 +i \tan ^{-1} (1/2)}=2+i$$ Now take $$z_k=\frac 1 {2\pi i k+\ln \sqrt 3 +i \tan ^{-1} (1/2)}$$ Not only does $e^{1/z_k} \to 2+i$ but we actually have $e^{1/z_k} = 2+i$ for all $k$.