# sequence of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a sequence of complex numbers $\{z_k\}$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} z_k = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} e^{1/z_k} =2+i$.

i tried finding the logarithm of (2 + i) and I found it to be Log (2 + i) = ln  √5 + i$\tan^{-1}(1/2)$.

I dont know what to do after this step. I saw the same question but they got $$e^{\ln \sqrt 3 +i \tan ^{-1} (1/2)}=2+i$$
 and i got Log (2 + i) = ln  $\sqrt{5}$   + i $\tan^{-1}(1/2)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How will you get a sequence, though?  What do you know about the complex exponential function?  You calculation of the logarithm is correct (so far as it goes.)

Comment: Write $w_k=1/z_k$. Then you want $e^{w_k}\to 2+i$ and $|w_k|\to\infty$. I think there's a sequence with $e^{w_k}=2+i$ and $|w_k|\to\infty$.

Comment: This question was asked on Mar 30 and my answer approved. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714106/find-a-sequence-of-complex-numbers-z-k-such-that-lim-limits-k-rightarro/2714256#2714256

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how did you get root of 3?, when i did the calculation for the logarithm r = root of 5. so that was where i was lost in the solution you provided.

Comment: I agree. It should have been $\sqrt 5$.